# Jquery datepicker using 2 dates on page

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a page with 2 date fields defined as shown (only diff is the name/id).

```
<input type="text" id="wsFromDate" name="wsFromDate" size="10" maxlength="10" class="font8_input" value="<%=wsFromDate%>" onfocus="javascript:fncAjaxClear()" />
```

If I click the image by the first date field, the datepicker pops up.
If I then click in the second date field, the original datepicker stays visible, unless I click the image on the second date field.
However, if I select another input field on the form, the datepicker closes.

What I would like to heapen is on clicking in the second date box, the datepicker associated with the first date field to close.

The jquery code is

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif",
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        buttonImageOnly: true
})
$( "#wsFromDate" ).datepicker();
$( "#wsToDate" ).datepicker();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/htpgB/5/

This will hide any instance of jQuery's ui-datepicker whenever a "datepicker field" loses focus.

```
$(function() {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "http://cymbio.cysive.com/images/calendar.gif",
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
    $( "#wsFromDate" ).datepicker();
    $( "#wsToDate" ).datepicker();

    $(':data("datepicker")').on('blur', function() {
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
    });
});

function fncAjaxClear() {
    $('div.AjaxSuggest').html('').css('border-width', 0);
}
```

Comment: Can't see anything in the other function which would cause a problem.  [code]    function fncAjaxClear() 
    {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++)
 {if (inputs[i].getAttribute('className') == 'AjaxSuggest' || inputs[i].getAttribute('class') == 'AjaxSuggest')
      {inputs[i].innerHTML = '';
      inputs[i].style.borderWidth = '0px';
      }
     }
    }[/code]

Comment: I've updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htpgB/1/) to include your `DIV` needs, plus offered a jQuery solution.  Everything works as it's supposed to.  Does it work for you? If so, what's the difference between it and what you have? Have you looked at the console? Any errors?

Comment: Thanks Ayman.  I've looked at this, and when I click into the second date field, the datepicker from the first date field is still shown.  If I click the second image, the 'second datepicker loads, and the first disappears.  Like the change to my javascript code though for the div updating :-).

Comment: Is there anyway to detmine what datepickers are on the form and close them all in my fncAjaxClear, or would that be a 'cheat' way of doing it?

Comment: Sorry; maybe I've not been clear.  I want the datepicker to only be displayed from the image, not on entry to the input box.  If I click on the image for wsFromDate, this should load the datepicker, but then on clicking into wsToDate (not the image), I want the wsFromDate datepicker to hide.

Comment: Alright... [this](http://jsfiddle.net/htpgB/4/) _has_ to work! http://jsfiddle.net/htpgB/4/

Comment: Yes; that does what I want.  However, can I achieve the same effect by jquery identifying all datepickers on the form, and hiding them, rather than naming each id?  I do this to remove the a class from all input fields on a form.  Could something similar be done for this? $("input.input_error").removeClass('input_error');

Answer (score 0):

change the shown on property to

showOn: "both"

**Edit:** Add the following

```
    $('#wsFromDate').click(function(){
        $( "#wsToDate" ).datepicker('hide');
    });
    $('#wsToDate').click(function(){
        $( "#wsFromDate" ).datepicker('hide');
    })
```

Comment: I want the datepicker to only be displayed from the image, not on entry to the input box. If I click on the image for wsFromDate, this should load the datepicker, but then on clicking into wsToDate (not the image), I want the wsFromDate datepicker to hide

Answer (score -1):

You can add this code to open, when you click on an input field (*wsFromDate* or *wsToDate*), the datepicker closing the other:

```
$('#wsFromDate').click(function() {
    $("#wsFromDate").datepicker("show");
});
$('#wsToDate').click(function() {
    $("#wsToDate").datepicker("show");
});
```

**UPDATE**

This code could help you:

```
$('#wsFromDate').blur(function() {
    $(this).datepicker("hide");
});
$('#wsToDate').blur(function() {
    $(this).datepicker("hide");
});
```

This should work also with `focusout` instead of `blur`.

The previous code became useless.

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure to fully understand your last comment... to close a whatever datepicker without having to define a close event for each one you could add a class selector like

```
class="font8_input datepicker"
```

and use this code:

```
    $('.datepicker').blur(function() {
        $(this).datepicker("hide");
    });
```

You could use the same `font8_input` if no issue with it.

Comment: Tried this, but it causes the datepicker to load when I click into the input field, but I only want it to be shown when the image is clicked.  It does, however, close the other datepicker.

Comment: @Keith now I well understand what you need

Comment: @macgyver How do you close the datepicker after you use it?

Comment: @Ayman you're right, I misunderstood what Keith is looking for. I thinked just Keith needs to switch the right datepicker without think how to close it after

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9yTpR/)  Please see this link.  When I load a datepicker, but then click in the third input box, the datepicker closes, irrespective of which field it is linked to.  I want to achieve this feature, but ideally, without having to have a close event for each date picker.  I would like to be able to achieve this automatically (from an option within datepicker), or by amending my fncAjaxClear script to close all datepickers on the form.

Comment: If I well understood your needs my new update should allow to close whatever datepicker without having to define a close event for each datepicker